# i need to restrict the results based on the searched key like - full text search

Tags: php, elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-5, n-gram

I am using edge ngram with 2 to 25 range.

I am trying to search keyword like 'testing' ,but i am getting results like 'testing' and the word like 'test'.

if i am search key is 'test' in that case both i can get like test and testing .

what should  i need to do get only result 'testing' on search key 'testing' , it should not match 'test'

My index config :

```
$config = '{"settings": {
                    "number_of_shards": 1, 
                    "analysis": {
                        "filter": {
                            "autocomplete_filter": { 
                                "type":     "edge_ngram",
                                "min_gram": 2,
                                "max_gram": 20
                            }
                        },
                        "analyzer": {
                            "autocomplete": {
                                "type":      "custom",
                                "tokenizer": "standard",
                                "filter": [
                                    "lowercase",
                                    "autocomplete_filter" 
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "/":{}
                }}';
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `keyword` as a [search time analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) that way it will not tokenize your search term and will bring you the expected Search results.